# cannot use `BottomNavigationView` and `ViewPager` and `TabLayout` simultaneously

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, bottomnavigationview

I did so much researches in the internet and the conclusion was that we cannot use `BottomNavigationView` and `ViewPager` and `TabLayout` simultaneously. but there are a lot of app such as Instagram that merged them.
my question is that how can they do that? do they use a special trick or not?

Comment: Did you try to use them together?

Comment: How have you proven that Instagram uses those three classes? There are other horizontal swiping solutions besides `ViewPager`, such as `RecyclerView`. There are lots of tab libraries. There are various bottom navigation libraries. Perhaps they use some other combination than the three that you feel cannot be used together.

Comment: That's exactly my question. do they use other libraries or not?Do you have another solution for me to have the same function as instagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create bottomNavigationView  in activity and attach fragment in it with this code when click a on item of it:

```
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(frameId, fragment, "fragTransaction");
        transaction.commit();
```

and then create a fragment wiht a tabLayout and viewPager to control child fragment in it and you most using to control fragment in viewPagerAdapter

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(frameId, fragment, "fragTransaction");
    transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not difficult to use bottomNavigationView with ViewPager.

1. In your layout declare both of these controls.
2. Setup viewPageAdapter and add fragments to it, set adapter to viewPager.
3. Setup bottomNavigationView overriding onNavigationItemSelectedListener, which now will be setting current item of viewPagerAdapter.

Do you need more detailed code examples, or you are ready to rock?

Comment: Your way is useful for the condition that the BouumNavigation itself sets with the view pager...I want to have a viewpager in one item of the BottomNavigationView that has been set with the tabLayout.